# Using prefetch_related and aggregations to avoid n+1 issue with Django database queries for model with time series data

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, aggregation

I am trying to avoid an obscene amount of database queries in a Django app. In the app I am monotoring a number of suggestions (model: Suggestion) that can be voted for (model: Vote).

The Vote model does not store each individual vote. Instead the total number of votes for a suggestion are stored at regular intervals. A suggestion of "Better ice cream" could have "10 votes at 8:10", "12 votes at 8:20", "25 votes at 8:30", etc.

I have created a very ineffecient loop with some major n+1 issues to calculate the number of new votes per day per suggestion.

I am looking for a more efficient (probably single) queryset than the current ones for the same functionality. I know that I should probably create some kind of annotation by dates of votes on "suggestions" in views.py and then annotate that by my aggregate function that calculates the number of votes on each day, but I cannot figure out how to actually chain this together.

Here's my current working but very inefficient code:

models.py:

```
class Suggestion(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    suggested_date = models.DateField()
​
class Vote(models.Model):
    suggestion = models.ForeignKey('Suggestion', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    votes = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    # Proces votes per day per suggestion
    suggestions = Suggestion.objects.prefetch_related('vote_set')
    votes_per_day_per_suggestion = {}
    for suggestion in suggestions:
        votes_per_day_per_suggestion[suggestion.title] = {}
        votes = suggestion.vote_set
        suggestion_dates = votes.dates('timestamp', 'day') # n+1 issue
        for date in suggestion_dates:
            date_min_max = votes.filter(timestamp__date=date).aggregate(votes_on_date=(Max('votes') - Min('votes'))) # n+1 issue
            votes_per_day_per_suggestion[suggestion.title][date] = date_min_max['votes_on_date']
    context['votes_per_day_per_suggestion'] = votes_per_day_per_suggestion
    return render(request, 'borgerforslag/index.html', context)
```

Template output:

```
Better toilet paper (number of votes per day):
19. october 2021: 23
20. october 2021: 19
21. october 2021: 18
22. october 2021: 9
23. october 2021: 25
24. october 2021: 34
25. october 2021: 216
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you all suggestions, dates and sum of votes in a values queryset

```
from django.db.models import Max, Min
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate


def index(request):
    suggestions = Suggestion.objects.annotate(
        date=TruncDate('vote__timestamp')
    ).order_by(
        'id', 'date'
    ).annotate(
        sum=Max('vote__votes') - Min('vote__votes')
    )
    return render(request, 'borgerforslag/index.html', {'suggestions': suggestions})
```

Then in template use [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) to group all those results by the suggestion

```
{% regroup suggestions by title as suggestions_grouped %}

<ul>
{% for suggestion in suggestions_grouped %}
    <li>{{ suggestion.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for date in suggestion.list %}
          <li>{{ date.date }}: {{ date.sum }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me there. I suggested an edit to reflect that I am not saving the number of added votes per timestamp in the Vote model, but instead the total number of votes at a time timestamp, so instead of Sum('vote__votes'), Max('vote__votes') - Min('vote__votes') should be calculated.

Comment: @Morten Ah, Vote contains a running total of votes or snapshot in time of the number of votes?

Comment: A snapshot in time of the total number of votes for a suggestion. If votes at 8:10 is 10, 10 people in total have voted for the suggestion. If votes at 8:20 is 13, 13 people in total have voted for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need is `values()`, `annotate()`, and `order_by()` to get the number of votes per day per suggestion.  This here should work

```
Vote.objects.all() \
    .values('timestamp__date', 'suggestion') \
    .annotate(num_votes=Count('votes') \
    .order_by('timestamp__date')
```

Although, your output example is not of number of votes per day per suggestion, and seems to be number of votes per day.  That can be achieved by removing suggestion from the query like this:

```
Vote.objects.all() \
    .values('timestamp__date') \
    .annotate(num_votes=Count('votes') \
    .order_by('timestamp__date')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid using Count does not work with the data model, but maybe my question should have been more precise. The Vote model is storing the _total number of votes_ at specific timestamps "Better ice cream" could have "10 TOTAL votes at 8:10", "12 TOTAL votes at 8:20", "25 TOTAL votes at 8:30", etc.